# Unexpected HTTP 500 error when user logs in on LocalHost, but login is successful on live site

Tags: laravel, http, authentication

The code I have pulled from the production server to my localhost server is identical. On the live site, the user can login as normal however on Localhost I cannot. I am using Laravel 5.1 for this project along with a XAMMP server.

The issue cannot be with the source code- as it is the same on the live site as it is on my machine. And it works as it should on the live site. Therefore I'm guessing the issue lies in my XAMMP configuration settings, however I am unsure where to start.

Comment: check /storage/logs/laravel.log and tell us what it says

Comment: The file is 73MB big and Laravel is only showing the first 2.4 MB of the file. The logs date back to 2016

Comment: you only have to read the bottom of it

Comment: Since it's local, you can always delete the old log and it'll create a new, empty one.

Comment: I think the error logging was deleted as laravel.log doesn't indicate anything useful and it doesn't update. I tried to turn it back on in global.php but I think the original developer may have deleted the file. Sorry, but I really don't know what could be going wrong. Something I need to do in the xampp configuration file maybe?

Comment: Dam, so someone looks through old posts, with 3 downvotes already on it, that's already closed. And just thinks 'I'll add value by downvoting again'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If page returns **HTTP 500 Error** it means that somewhere is syntax error or script can't run correctly. Maybe your settings set for non-local server?

Comment: How would I go about changing the settings set for this sort of stuff. The configuration file for Xampp apache server?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the XAMPP configuration file and its index.php file. I had a conversation with the original developer who guided me through how to congfigure this and all is resolved now. I needed to change some permissions with the files I had downloaded RWX etc, as well as the root file of my project files.